# sinon stub not restoring properly if the stubbing method is deconstructed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

Given the test codes below:

subAuthCall:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')
const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox()

function stubSuccessCall() {
    return sandbox.stub(authorization, 'authorize').returns({enabled: true});
}

function stubFailedCall() {
    return sandbox.stub(authorization, 'authorize').returns({enabled: false});

function restoreSub() {
    sandbox.restore();
}
```

in the authorization.js file, I have:

```
function authorize(data) {
    return data.enabled;
}

module.exports = {
    authorize
}
```

and then in the middleware, I have:

```
const {authorize} = require('./authorization')


async function check() {
    //import auth data
    console.log(authorize(data))
    if (authorize(data)) {
        //resolve to true
    } else {
        //reject
    }
}
```

Then in the test case, I called:

```
afterEach(authorizationStub.restorStub);

describe('auth testing', () => {
    it('test successful', () => {
        authorizationStub.stubSuccessCall();
        return check().then(res => {expect(res.result).to.equl(true)});
    })

    it('test failed', () => {
        authorizationStub.stubFailedCall();
        return check().then(res => {expect(res.result).to.equl(false)});
    })
})
```

It's a overly simplified auth logic and test case. The weird problem I had is that if I run both test cases, it prints out:

1 - test successful

true // from console.log(authorize(data))

2 - test failed

true // from console.log(authorize(data))

The 1st test case passed and the 2nd one failed (because the stubbing didn't return the right result)

but in the test failed, case, it supposed to return false as how I stub it in stubFailedCall, but it still has the same result in stubSuccessCall. I have verified the restoreStub is called.

I accidentally came across the fix: In the middleware, I used to have:

```
const {authorize} = require('./authorization')
...
```

but if I changed this to:

```
const auth = require('./authorization')
```

and then in the codes, instead of:

```
authorize(data)
```

I do:

```
auth.authorize(data)
```

This will work - both test cases will pass without any other changes.

My question is, why sinon stub/restoring stub didn't work if I deconstruct the authorize call in the middleware, but if I use an object to make the call, it will work? What's the mechanism behind this?

Comment: What happens if you fix the typo `afterEach(authorizationStub.restorStub)`?

Comment: First of all, use `mocha-sinon` to not care about stub restoring. And then there's a problem because `authorization` module isn't reloaded. You need to decache and re-require it on every test.

Comment: You'll find the answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591287/200987 Not the original issue, but the one relating to destructuring.